# How to correctly pass arguments on Common Lisp?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

I'm currently reading Practical Common Lisp, and I decided to try and improve its first example ([simple database](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/practical-a-simple-database.html)), just to practice.

I'm trying to make the `update` function more generic, like the `select` function.

Here's my code, it runs but doesn't actually update anything like it should.

```
 (defun make-if-expr (field value)
   `(if ,value (setf (getf row ,field) ,value)))

 (defun make-if-list (fields)
   (loop while fields
      collecting (make-if-expr (pop fields) (pop fields))))

 (defun update (selector-fn &rest clauses)
   (setf *db*
     (mapcar
      #'(lambda (row)
          (when (funcall selector-fn row)
            (apply #'make-if-list clauses))
          row)
      *db*)))
```

This is modified from the original source code, available in the link.

As an example, using `((:TITLE "Title" :ARTIST "Artist" :RATING 7 :RIPPED T))` as a database, typing in `(update (where :title "Title") (list :title "New Title"))` in the REPL should change the title to "New Title". It doesn't, though.

There is no error, no nothing. It just doesn't work.

Since I'm a complete beginner at Common Lisp, can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong? I'm pretty sure I'm not passing arguments to functions correctly.

Comment: Please format your code properly. It is not readable now. Emacs can help you.

Comment: Do you mean indentation? If so, I fixed it.

Comment: How about a reproducable test case?

Comment: @RainerJoswig what do you mean? Like calling `update` in the REPL and posting the output?

Comment: that would be a good start...

Comment: The last `*db*` should be on its own line - Emacs should highlight it.

Comment: @sds done, but Emacs didn't highlight it.

Answer (score 2):

`MAKE-IF-LIST` creates a list of lists and returns it. You are not doing anything with them and thus nothing happens.

It's also not clear why you are creating the lists, since you could just write a function which does the update.

Comment: Wouldn't writing a function to do the update require code specific to each column, as shown in Practical Common Lisp? Avoiding that is what I'm trying to learn.

Comment: @GabrielHuwe: I can't see why that would be neccessary.

Comment: @GabrielHuwe, Rainer has a point here, since you're using `setf` of `getf` all the time anyway.  Your `make-if-expr` should probably be named `update-if` (and `make-if-list` named `update-list-if`), and instead of generating an expression, it should actually run that expression, or in other words, remove the backquote and the commas.

Comment: @acelent, That worked. I now realize how convoluted and messy my original code was. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are trying to make `update` work similiarly to how `where` was implemented with a macro at the end of the chapter. In that case, what you're doing wrong is simply that your `update` is not a macro. You need to change it into one, and use the backtick syntax to evaluate the necessary parts (`selector-fn` and `(make-if-list ...)`):

```
(defmacro update (selector-fn &rest clauses)
  `(setf *db*
         (mapcar
          #'(lambda (row)
              (when (funcall ,selector-fn row)
                ,@(make-if-list clauses))
              row)
          *db*)))

(setf *db* (list (list :TITLE "Title" :ARTIST "Artist" :RATING 7 :RIPPED T)))
(update (where :title "Title") :title "New Title")
*db*
; => ((:TITLE "New Title" :ARTIST "Artist" :RATING 7 :RIPPED T))
```

**Edit:** As Rainer Joswig said in the comments, the code above does have some problems. In reality you would have to make sure you don't evaluate variables multiple times, and you shouldn't use symbols that may be used by the surrounding code. The book should cover that in later chapters, but a better, although a bit more complicated, version of the code would look like this (Also see [coredumps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35148234/5747548) answer, since I didn't want to steal that into this):

```
;; You need to pass the `row-sym` here, because this can't 
;; rely on the row being called `row` (which it isn't).
;; You'll also want to see the answer by coredump regarding this.
(defun make-if-expr (field value row-sym)
  `(if ,value (setf (getf ,row-sym ,field) ,value)))

(defun make-if-list (fields row-sym)
  (loop while fields
     collecting (make-if-expr (pop fields) (pop fields) row-sym)))

(defmacro update (selector-fn &rest clauses)
  ;; You need to use `gensym` to generate unique names 
  ;; for all symbols you use in the expanded code.
  (let ((selector-sym (gensym "selector-fn"))
        (row-sym (gensym "row")))
    ;; Assign `selector-fn` into a variable. This avoids the 
    ;; function being built by the `where` macro multiple times.
    `(let ((,selector-sym ,selector-fn))
       (setf *db*
             (mapcar
              ;; You have to use the unique symbols generated above,
              ;; so the `*-sym` variables are evaluated with a comma.
              #'(lambda (,row-sym) 
                  (when (funcall ,selector-sym ,row-sym)
                    ,@(make-if-list clauses row-sym))
                  ,row-sym)
              *db*)))))
```

Comment: It's just that a macro makes generally no sense for this example.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Probably true, but that seems to be what GabrielHuwe was going for. Since it's just for practice, rather than a real application, I figured it would be best to show how to make it work rather than just give a completely different solution.

Comment: That's okay. But now that we have a macro, instead of a function, one needs to be aware of more things: for example the code for SELECTOR-FN is now executed on each iteration. Probably not what one would want...

Comment: @RainerJoswig That's a good point, but I'm pretty sure the book covers that in the later chapters. But I'll add a version of the code with gensyms and lets too.

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly related to your problem, but:

```
(defun make-if-expr (field value)
   `(if ,value (setf (getf row ,field) ,value)))
```

... injects `value` at two different places, which means it is going to be evaluated twice when non-nil. This is problematic if computing the value takes time or if it performes side-effects. You should probably introduce a variable to hold that value:

```
(defun make-if-expr (field value)
  (let ((symbol (gensym)))
   `(let ((,symbol ,value))
      (if ,symbol (setf (getf row ,field) ,symbol)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the wonderful tips everyone gave me, I was able to solve my problem.

I was trying to generate the `if`s inside the `update` function, which only makes sense using macros. Instead, I used a single function now.

This is my new code, hopefully it will be useful for people having similar problems:

```
 (defun update-if (field value row)
   (setf (getf row field) value))

 (defun update-if-list (fields row)
   (loop while fields
      do (update-if (pop fields) (pop fields) row)))

 (defun update (selector-fn &rest clauses)
   (setf *db*
     (mapcar
      #'(lambda (row)
          (when (funcall selector-fn row)
            (update-if-list clauses row))
          row)
      *db*)))
```

Comment: You don't need to `collect` in that loop. Just use a `do` instead. Actually, you don't need the `if` in `update-if` either (and having that will prevent you from assigning `nil` to a field).

Comment: Fixed. What differs between `do` and `collect` anyway?

Comment: `collect[ing]` returns a list of results from evaluating the form. `do` simply runs the code.